# computer vision - How to construct a 3d map?

Tags: computer-vision

I have some good basics -I think- in computervision (using openCV) and am considering to build a quadcopter to create a 3D maps while flying.

I would like to place a camera on each side of the quadcopter (ie, left, right, front and back) to continuously provide +/- 360 degrees images. Then stitch those four images together to get a -roughly speaking- 360 degree view.

I know that slam very often used for this types of things.
However I am kind of lost on where would be the best place to start and what algorithms I should look at.

What algorithms should I read about in order to be able to do this?

What would be the easiest way to proceed?

(The endgoal would be to eventually do object tracking in this 3d map)

Thanks

Comment: I think that your question is too broad and a bit unclear at the moment. Do you generate the images on fly? Have some 3D scene? Do you want answer about merging the cube of images to provide a better looking view? The [cube mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping) comes to mind. Could you identify the initial steps, and when you encounter some difficulties ask about them providing more context?

Comment: @Evil yes I generate the images on the fly. Yes I want a 3d scene. What I would like is some advice like "oh you want to do xx? Ok in that case look at algorithm xxx and personally I would avoid yyy because zzz ..."

Comment: Have you seen the [tour](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help)? It is not that simple, because you want do do xx, you can do it with like dozen of different approaches, using unknown constraints and solving undefined (to the reader) problems that you haven't yet encountered, like using Euler angles, which one to use? To switch at some point to quaternions. But it is not even obvious that you can rotate your object now. And the answers shouldn't be about personal opinion, so the advices are not very good fit here.